# Grep regex capturing issue

Tags: regex, grep

Why this doesn't match the capturing group?

```
grep -rPo 'ServerMethod\(me\.[a-zA-Z]*\.([a-zA-Z]*)\)'
```

it returns :

```
test.js:ServerMethod(me.obProcedures.SaveProcess)    
test.js:ServerMethod(me.obProcedures.Commit)
```

but I need just:

```
SaveProcess            
Commit
```

cygwin version:
2.5.2(0.297/5/3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens so because `grep` does not return capture group contents, only the whole matches.

You may use `\K` match reset operator and and a positive lookahead instead:

```
grep -Po 'ServerMethod\(me\.[a-zA-Z]*\.\K[a-zA-Z]+(?=\))'
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/LEiTW8)

**Details**:

- `ServerMethod\(me\.` - matches a literal string `ServerMethod(me.`
- `[a-zA-Z]*` - 0 or more ASCII letters
- `\.` - a literal dot
- `\K` - omits the text matched so far from the match
- `[a-zA-Z]+`  - 1 or more ASCII letters
- `(?=\))`  - a positive lookahead that requires a `)` immediately to the right of the current location, but does not add it to the match (as it is a *non-consuming* pattern).

Alternatively, as a PCRE `grep` option is not always available, use `sed` with `grep`:

```
grep 'ServerMethod(me\.' | sed 's/.*ServerMethod(me\.[a-zA-Z]*\.\([a-zA-Z]*\)).*/\1/'
```

See [another demo](https://ideone.com/KM2Bl7).

Here, the patterns are POSIX BRE compliant:

- `ServerMethod(me\.` - matches a literal `ServerMethod(me.` text, `grep` gets the lines with this text
- `.*ServerMethod(me\.[a-zA-Z]*\.\([a-zA-Z]*\)).*` - matches a line that has

  - `.*` - any 0+ chars as many as possible
  - `ServerMethod(me\.` - a literal `ServerMethod(me.` text
  - `[a-zA-Z]*` - 0+ ASCII letters
  - `\.`  - a literal dot
  - `\([a-zA-Z]*\)`  - Capturing group 1 (referred to via `\1`): 0+ ASCII letters
  - `)` - a literal `)`
  - `.*` - any 0+ chars as many as possible

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you know why your code doesn't works on cygwin console ?

Comment: If you used `-P` option successfully with your previous attempt, it should work, else, you just can't use a PCRE pattern.